# How to convert an Application from Raphael 1.5.2 to Raphael 2.0?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I see this application on jsfiddl [jsfiddle with raphael 1.5.2](http://jsfiddle.net/allankiezel/FJrNN/)

When i'm trying to run it with raphael 2.0 i got some errors and some effects dont run!

How can i change the code to make it run with raphael 2.0?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with **scale** on **animate**

[The Raphael reference](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html) shows that to scale an object one could use something like this:

```
element.animate({transform: 's1.05'}, 200);
```

So by changing at the end of the fiddle, on the js part, in the for loop

```
this.animate({scale: '1.2'}, 200);
```

with

```
this.animate({transform: 's1.2'}, 200);
```

and

```
this.animate({scale: '1.05'}, 200);
```

with

```
this.animate({transform: 's1.05'}, 200);
```

the thing should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but dont really completly solve this problem : "el is undefined" => el.mouseover(function() {